# How do I add a score system to this Spritekit game?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I can't figure out a way to add a score system to my game.  Can someone please help me do this in a visual, GUI way?  Thanks very much. I have tried doing this with an int variable, but it won't work. If  you do help, again, thank you very much

```
import SpriteKit

let BallCategoryName = "ball"
let PaddleCategoryName = "paddle"
let BlockCategoryName = "block"
let BlockNodeCategoryName = "blockNode"
let BallCategory   : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0 //     00000000000000000000000000000001
let BottomCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1 //   00000000000000000000000000000010
let BlockCategory  : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2 // 00000000000000000000000000000100
let PaddleCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3 // 00000000000000000000000000001000

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var isFingerOnPaddle = false
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)

    let bottomRect = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, 1)
    let bottom = SKNode()
    bottom.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: bottomRect)
    addChild(bottom)

    // 1. Create a physics body that borders the screen
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    // 2. Set the friction of that physicsBody to 0
    borderBody.friction = 0
    // 3. Set physicsBody of scene to borderBody
    self.physicsBody = borderBody

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

    let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
    ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))

    ball.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody!.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody!.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if let body = physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation) {
        if body.node!.name == PaddleCategoryName {
            println("Began touch on paddle")
            isFingerOnPaddle = true
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // 1. Check whether user touched the paddle
    if isFingerOnPaddle {
        // 2. Get touch location
        var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        var touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var previousLocation = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)

        // 3. Get node for paddle
        var paddle = childNodeWithName(PaddleCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode

        // 4. Calculate new position along x for paddle
        var paddleX = paddle.position.x + (touchLocation.x - previousLocation.x)

        // 5. Limit x so that paddle won't leave screen to left or right
        paddleX = max(paddleX, paddle.size.width/2)
        paddleX = min(paddleX, size.width - paddle.size.width/2)

        // 6. Update paddle position
        paddle.position = CGPointMake(paddleX, paddle.position.y)
    }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    isFingerOnPaddle = false
}
```

}

Comment: ake a look at :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/87232/make-game-like-mega-jump-sprite-kit-swift-part-2

scoring system

Answer (score 2):

To add a score system to your game, you would first need to keep track of your score, which can be an Int variable.

As for displaying it visually as GUI, you would use a SKLabelNode to represent the text on your screen and update it depending on the current score of the user which will be represented by an Int variable that you used.

As for persisting the data, check out NSCoding, NSUserDefaults to store that score so that it can be reused again the next time the user runs the app.